# Get value from Mongodb async driver document

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I have some documents in my **MongoDB** database.

Looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5598d61b0cfb246b90daa3f7" }, "name" : "Sarah", "uuid" : "488f69e9-8070-40f0-8c0a-b5d0bd53bdfe", "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1436079643735 }, "istested" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5598d6260cfb2461d4ad4f98" }, "name" : "Omah", "uuid" : "93e572c0-8acd-4397-8487-4d458bbafa8d", "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1436079654217 }, "istested" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5598d6300cfb246bace63cef" }, "name" : "Secret", "uuid" : "60e1413e-49e3-4315-a970-7111d55fe8d1", "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1436079664902 }, "istested" : false }
```

Now I wan to get the name 
    where `uuid = 93e572c0-8acd-4397-8487-4d458bbafa8d` (Omah)

How do I do this? (Using com.mongodb.async)

Answer (score 0):

To get the name where `uuid = 93e572c0-8acd-4397-8487-4d458bbafa8d`, use the **[`find()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#find--)** method to query the collection, create a filter to pass to the **[`find()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#find--)** method to get a subset of the documents in your collection, use the projection parameter in the **[Projections](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/builders/projections/)** helper class for the find operation to limit the fields returned, and then call the **[`first()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoIterable.html#first--)** method on the **[`find()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#find--)** operation to return the first document or null rather than a cursor. For example,

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

Block<Document> printDocument = new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document.toJson());
    }
};

collection.find(eq("uuid", "93e572c0-8acd-4397-8487-4d458bbafa8d"))
          .projection(fields(include("name"), excludeId()))
          .first(printDocument);
```

will print the document:

```
{ "name" : "Omah" }
```

Comment: @Robert I've updated the answer with the Projections helper class that you need to import for that to work.